# Button click timing a php game

Tags: php, timing

I would like to put the 1/1000 second when a button is clicked into a session variable - `$_SESSION['Click'] or $_COOKIE['Click']`

```
echo '<a href="index.php?level=done"><img src="./cat.jpg" width="'.$imgwidth.'" height="'.$imgwidth.'"></a>';
```

The site is called again and the new level is built.
The 1/1000 second when the level is built shall be stored in another session variable `$_SESSION['Begin']`

Then `$_SESSION['TimeNotMeasured'] += $_SESSION['Begin'] - $_SESSION['Click'] or $_COOKIE['CLick']`
What would be the solution to get and store the exact time of click?

I finished the Game and it works - but I need a much better solution to measure the time between the moment when the level is finished and the milliseconds or seconds until the next level is built and ready.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought / Made a tested and working Solution:

```
function myFunction() 
{
    const d = new Date();
    let time = d.getTime();
    d.setTime(time + 5000);
    let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "time="+time+";"+expires+";path=/";
    window.open('index.php?level=yes',"_top");
}
echo '<span id="tick" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="./cat_asis.jpg" width="'.$imgwidth.'" height="'.$imgwidth.'"></span>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You're talking about things that happen in the browser:

- Clicks.
- Levels that finish.

You therefore have to measure these things in the browser, not in PHP. You could for instance use [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now), like so:

```
const t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`Call to doSomething took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);
```

After you've timed it you can send the information back to the server, with a delay and store it there.

Comment: Well - whatever happens on the browser. There must be a way to detect the moment of a mouse click or touch on a screen and store it in a variable ... 

there is always a workaround

The question is - which addon, which trick is the solution?

Comment: @Elvenlord Yes, of course there is. I never understood, from your question, you had a problem with that. Detecting mouse clicks is easy and each click comes with a timestamp. Here is [an example of a keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp), but the same applies to mouse clicks. Just replace "keypress" by "click".